An equivalent classical circuit for Hadamard gate
In principle, we can simulate any Quantum circuit via a classical circuit. However, this simulation could be inefficient. (Church-Turing thesis)
Together, Hadamard and Toffolli are universal gate sets for quantum computing. I can see an equivalent circuit for Toffoli using XOR and AND as below: (image from here)


Can I get a similar circuit-like architecture for Hadamard Gate?


My attempt:
The main hurdle I can think of is the probabilistic nature of the output of Hadamard gate. It seems equivalent to asking if I can find a classical deterministic circuit for simulating a fair coin flip. Thus related to the open $BPP=P$ question.
Or, is there a known circuit construction for Hadamard gate?

This related cs.SE post could be helpful:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/168373/161641

No. A classical Hadamard gate has to act like a coin flip gate on a computational basis state, but must act like the identity when squared. That is, it needs to “remember” whether the input was $0$ or $1$.
Ryan O’Donnell is posting lectures from his undergrad course at Carnegie Mellon (link), and his lecture 12 discusses this point.

Thanks! the last 3 minutes of Ryan's video do opine on the coin flip analogy and Hadamard gate.

I think there is one more way to support your answer:
It seems to me that a classical circuit (of constant size) for Hadamard would imply an efficient classical algorithm for any quantum algorithm.

Claim: Convert any given quantum circuit into {H, toffolli} form. Then, the constant-size classical gate construction for H and Toffoli is used. Solvay-Kitaev implies {H, toffoli} conversion is always efficient.
Let me know if there is a flaw in the above argument.

Makes sense  to me
